# TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable despite being able to index

Tags: python, pandas, list, nonetype

I have a list that I am able to index totally fine outside of a loop. When I put it in a loop, though, I get the "TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable" error. I have no idea what is going on.

Here is the code:

```
GDPforDataTables = []
ct = 0
for x in range(len(pdcovid)):
  if pdcovid['date'][x] == '11/30/2020':
for t in range(len(pdEcon)):
  if pdEcon['Country Name'][t] == pdcovid['location'][x]:
    GDPforDataTables.append([pdEcon['Country Name'][t], Final_GDP[t], pdEcon['2019 Score'][t], pdcovid['total_cases'][x], pdcovid['total_deaths'][x], pdcovid['total_tests'][x]])

 for x in range(len(GDPforDataTables)):
   for t in range(len(pdHuman)):
      if GDPforDataTables[x][0] == pdHuman['countries'][t]:
         GDPforDataTables[x] = GDPforDataTables[x].append(pdHuman['hf_score'][t])
```

Comment: python is 0 index based, so you may find luck doing something like `for x in range(len(pdcovid) -1 )` instead. You may be getting that error just on the last loop?

Comment: Please provide a complete, self contained example. While doing that you are most likely to find out what is the real problem. A tell here is that you are using range(len(aDict)) and then indexing aDict['key'][x]. did you mean range(len(aDict['key'])) ?

Comment: Looks like the formatting got messed up? As is, this should raise a `SyntaxError` because that first `if` is empty.

Comment: Yes - formatting got messed up on the stack overflow post (not messed up in the real code) and the "-1" doesn't work either. Also, len(list) should work fine. In regards to the self-contained example, that is basically it. The dataframes are fairly normal and I have written essentially the same thing 25+ times using different variables and all works fine. It did sort the list at one point, then deleted that code... Could that be the problem?